# How to display data about 3000 record in datatable jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables plugin.

When data contains 50 records , it works fine, But when I load data with ~3000 records, datatable does not show and the following error appears in the console.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) `BUS/WebService.asmx/VIEW_DATA`

```js
var table = $('#div_table').DataTable({
    "processing": false,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "../BUS/WebService.asmx/VIEW_DATA",
        "dataType": "json",
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "type": "POST",
        data: function (data) { return "{'user_id_temp':'" + id + "'}"; },
        dataSrc: function (json) { return $.parseJSON(json.d); }
    },
    "language": {
        "lengthMenu": "Show _MENU_",
        "zeroRecords": "Not found - Sorry",
        "info": "Page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_ (_MAX_ records)",
        "infoEmpty": "No records",
        "infoFiltered": "",
        "sSearch": "Search"
    },
    // .......
)};
```

Can you tell me about this issue? What's happening here?

Comment: Can you screenshot the result and explain what you expect?

Comment: May be it takes time to load!

Comment: I'm not sure , I wait about 30 minutes @@ . It just not show .

Comment: Can you try about 500 records and let us know what happens?

Comment: Sina , seem about 500 records , datatable not show , it's not work .

Comment: @BrianCrist have you tried opening your browser console to see if you have any errors? Press f12 in your browser and look for the console tab. I know it works for 50 but maybe `datatables` is crashing on one record.

Comment: I know , this is console log `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) BUS/WebService.asmx/VIEW_DATA`. Normal , data 10~50 record , it's work , no error , but when i test number of data large , more than 500 records, it's not work.

Comment: Your JavaScript code is OK. If you get error with code `500`, look for error log on your server.